# How to answer the recommendation questions in Festival Plaza?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

The guests in Festival Plaza sometimes ask me to recommend them some place to go to in my own Festival Plaza. For instance, they sometimes ask "Take me to a place that Pokémon can enjoy!", while some other times it is "Take me to a place you think I'd like!". If you are answering correctly, you get some Festival Coins from the guests, while in the other case they just get upset and don't reward you.

What kind of facility should I recommend them to go to when I am asked a specific sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a total of 8 sentences that someone can ask you when they want you to recommend a place. According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Festival_Plaza#Recommendations), here is the list of possible requests and their answers:

- "We're hungry. Take us to a yummy place": Restaurants.
- "I want to shop. Will you recommend a good place to shop?": Goody shops.
- "Take me to a place that Pokémon can enjoy": Bouncy houses, restaurants, haunted houses.
- "Take me to a place where I can see real skilled work": Dye shops, restaurants, fortune-teller tents.
- "Take me to a place where I can treat myself!": Dye shops, fortune-tellers tents, goody shops, lottery shops.
- "Take me to an exciting place!": Fortune-teller tents, haunted houses, lottery shops.
- "Take me to a place where my Pokémon can play!": Bouncy houses, haunted houses.

The 8th sentence is a bit different. "Take me to a place you think I'd like!" has a totally random answer everytime someone asks it. So for this one, only luck will help you.

Here is the list of the corresponding shops for each category, so you can select the good one in the list when you're being asked:

- Restaurants: Rare Kitchen, Battle Table, Friendship Café, Friendship Parlor.
- Goody shops: Ball Shop, General Store, Battle Tore, Soft Drink Parlor, Pharmacy, Effort Shop.
- Bouncy houses : Clink-Clunk Land, Stomp-Stomp House, Phew-Phew Gym, Thymp-Bump Park.
- Dyes shops: Team Red, Team Yellow, Team Green, Team Blue, Team Orange, Team Navy Blue, Team Purple, Team Pink.
- Fortune-teller tents: Kanto Tent, Johto Tent, Hoenn Tent, Sinnoh Tent, Unova Tent, Kalos Tent, Pokémon House.
- Haunted houses: Ghosts' Den, Trick Room, Confuse Ray.
- Lottery shops: Big Dreams, Gold Rush, Treasure Hunt.